# Pandas select columns and data dependant on header

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, columnheader

I have a large .csv file. I want to select only the column with he time/date and 20 other columns which I know by header.

As a test I try to take only the column with the header 'TIMESTAMP' I know this is 
4207823 rows long in the .csv and it only contains dates and times. The code below selects the TIMESTAMP column but also carries on to take values from other columns as shown below:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas

low_memory=False
f = pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\mmso2\Google Drive\MABL Wind\_Semester 2 2016\Wind Farm Info\DataB\DataB - NaN2.csv', dtype = object)#convert file to variable so it can be edited

time = f[['TIMESTAMP']]
time = time[0:4207823]#test to see if this stops time taking other data
print time
```

output

```
                  TIMESTAMP
0       2007-08-15 21:10:00
1       2007-08-15 21:20:00
2       2007-08-15 21:30:00
3       2007-08-15 21:40:00
4       2007-08-15 21:50:00
5       2007-08-15 22:00:00
6       2007-08-15 22:10:00
7       2007-08-15 22:20:00
8       2007-08-15 22:30:00
9       2007-08-15 22:40:00
10      2007-08-15 22:50:00
11      2007-08-15 23:00:00
12      2007-08-15 23:10:00
13      2007-08-15 23:20:00
14      2007-08-15 23:30:00
15      2007-08-15 23:40:00
16      2007-08-15 23:50:00
17      2007-08-16 00:00:00
18      2007-08-16 00:10:00
19      2007-08-16 00:20:00
20      2007-08-16 00:30:00
21      2007-08-16 00:40:00
22      2007-08-16 00:50:00
23      2007-08-16 01:00:00
24      2007-08-16 01:10:00
25      2007-08-16 01:20:00
26      2007-08-16 01:30:00
27      2007-08-16 01:40:00
28      2007-08-16 01:50:00
29      2007-08-16 02:00:00 #these are from the TIMESTAMP column
...                     ...
679302              221.484 #This is from another column 
679303                  NaN
679304  2015-09-23 06:40:00
679305                  NaN
679306                  NaN
679307  2015-09-23 06:50:00
679308                  NaN
679309                  NaN
679310  2015-09-23 07:00:00
```

Comment: parameter `usecols` in `pandas.read_csv`  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to an error in the input file so simple use of `usecols` in `pandas.read_csv` worked.

code below demonstrates the selection of a few columns of data

```
import csv
import pandas

low_memory=False



    #read only the selected columns
    df = pandas.read_csv('DataB - Copy - Copy.csv',delimiter=',', dtype = object,
    usecols=['TIMESTAMP', 'igmmx_U_77m', 'igmmx_U_58m', ])
    print df # see what the data looks like
    outfile = open('DataB_GreaterGabbardOnly.csv','wb')#somewhere to write the data to
    df.to_csv(outfile)#save selection to the blank .csv created above
```